# Variables in decorators without syntactic sugar

Tags: python, python-decorators

There is code:

```
def bread(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('</------\>')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('<\______/>')

    return wrapper


def ingredients(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('tomato')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('lettuce')

    return wrapper


def burger(food='bacon'):
    print(food)


burger = bread(ingredients(burger))
burger()
```

Output:

```
</------\>
tomato
bacon
lettuce
<\______/>
```

How you can understand there are present two decorators without syntactic sugar.

`burger = bread(ingredients(burger))`
like

```
@bread
@ingredients
def burger(...):
...
```

I want to push a some variable to the `burger()`. If I change `burger = bread(ingredients(burger))` to `burger = bread(ingredients(burger("cheese")))` I get an errors.

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

## My questions:

Main question: I learn decorators in detail and I want to know how variables transfer in decorators without syntactic sugar?

### Subquestionals:

1. Why does not work `burger = bread(ingredients(burger("cheese")))` in my case?
2. How are variables actually passed to the `wrapper` sub function in `bread` and `ingredients` functions in without syntactic sugar?
3. Are there difference between work with variables passed to the decorator function and decorator sub function (Question #2) without syntactic sugar? Or the code will be the same - level add only.

I mean this exanple in Q. 3:

```
def bread(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(func):
        def subwrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print('</------\>')
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            print('<\______/>')

        return subwrapper
    return wrapper

@bread('test')
def burger(food='bacon'):
    print(food)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76696603/8497844) gives a good answer, but I'm structuring and adding the answer.

1. We have to unterstand that Python uses a function that can be set to a variable. As I said [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76696603/8497844) give good answer. I'm not explain better.

I can not change `burger` in `burger = bread(ingredients(burger('cheese')))` but I can change `bread(ingredients(burger))('cheese')` and so function `bread` have `cheese` in it.

`bread(ingredients(burger))('cheese')`

Output:

```
</------\>
tomato
cheese
lettuce
<\______/>
```

If be honest `'cheese'` pass step by step to `burger` anyway.

2. What we have:

```
def bread(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('</------\>')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('<\______/>')

    return wrapper
```

This is important, pay attention `return wrapper`. This mean function return function (not variable, not `return wrapper()`).

I.e. `burger = bread(ingredients(burger))` gets the function `ingredients` and `bread`, so in the final we have `burger` - this is a variable that getting all the functions of `wrapper`:

```
def burger(food='bacon'):
    print(food)
```

then

```
def burger(food='bacon'):
    print('tomato')
    print(food)
    print('lettuce')
```

then

```
def burger(food='bacon'):
    print('</------\>')
    print('tomato')
    print(food)
    print('lettuce')
    print('<\______/>')
```

If be honest in real we have something like this:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print('</------\>')
    print('tomato')
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    print('lettuce')
    print('<\______/>')
```

The last function `wrapper` save in variable `burger` and when we call `burger()` we call updated function with arguments.

3. Here is answer:

```
def first_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    def bread(func):
        def second_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print('</------\>')
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            print('<\______/>')

        return second_wrapper
    return bread

first_wrapper('sesame')(bread(ingredients(burger))('cheese'))
```

Output:

```
sesame
</------\>
tomato
cheese
lettuce
<\______/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to a decorator must be a function. `burger` is a function, `burger("cheese")` is a call to the function, not a reference to the function itself.

To get a reference to a function that passes an argument, use a lambda:

```
burger = bread(ingredients(lambda: burger("cheese")))
```

However, this won't actually work, because when the lambda is called, `burger` will have been redefined as the result of all these decorators. You either have to save the original value of `burger` in another variable and use that:

```
burger1 = burger
burger = bread(ingredients(lambda: burger1("cheese")))
```

or use a different name for the decorated function:

```
cheeseburger = bread(ingredients(lambda: burger("cheese")))
```

This isn't a problem when you use `@decorator` because the original function is in a closure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How I understand this is constaction doesn't show how variable transfer to `wrapper` sub function of `bread` and `ingredients` functions. It's sending to `burger`. Isn't it?